# Flutter : Picasso or Universal Image loader equivalent

Tags: android, ios, listview, picasso, flutter

I'm new to Google flutter sdk for developing app for Android and ios,
I want to load images in a large `ListView` ,
I want to load images asynchronously and using caching , in Android JAVA/Kotlin I use Picasso, how can I get similar behavior in Flutter?

official flutter `ListView` example : [What is the alternative to a ListView in Flutter](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#what-is-the-alternative-to-a-listview-in-flutter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to load and cache your images you could use the [CachedNetworkImageProvider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image). It is still in development, but working quite well.

Comment: thanks, it works but only in online mode.
I/flutter ( 3291): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown  resolving an image codec:  
I/flutter ( 3291): The method 'getFilePath' was called on null.  
I/flutter ( 3291): Receiver: null

Comment: and it doesn't have a default placholder for when error occured

Comment: You could combine it with a [FadeInImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) to use a placeholder. Not completely sure what happens when it errors.

Comment: @Mneckoee because of yours and others request I started working on it again today :). I just published an alpha version that includes a placeholder and an error widget: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image/versions/0.3.0-alpha